# how to perform operation on dataset (whose format is .csv) using java

Tags: java, dataset

I have movies dataset. I want to perform operation on that like 
1. find top 10 most viewed movies with name (Ascending order).
2. find top 20 rated movies.
3. Top 10 critics.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: My main recommendation would be to 1. Load the list of movies in. 2. Sort by views, ratings, or critics using https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator). 3. Read the top values from the sorted list. That's an overall guide, but you might want to post a more in depth question if you have problems with particular steps.

Comment: I can perform these operation using oracle but I don't have to use oracle or sql. I have only .csv file.

Comment: @Lalaland yup i can do that but how to fetch data from any file and store it into collections.

Comment: @Shivam For sophisticated uses, there are CSV libraries like https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator). If this is just a small project that doesn't need any complicated features, I recommend just manually reading the file line by line and splitting on the "," charcter. You can use [BufferedReader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) to read line by line. [String::split](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) should work for splitting.